# Retrieving a Property Value Inside a Custom Attribute

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Right now I have an attribute called Checkbox. We're using it because of our front end posts "On" and "Off" instead of true/false when a checkbox value is submitted.

Our goal is to parse the on/off values and convert them to true/false before they get to the JSON converter, so they can be picked up as a boolean.

I've considered using this attribute to handle that.

```
    [Checkbox]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(InvariantConverter))]
    public bool CheckboxInputValue { get; set; }
```

I need access to the value of the property inside of the checkbox attribute and then need the ability to modify the value.

Open to suggestions and thoughts here.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store per-instance data in an attribute property since the attribute is created when using the reflection API on the class.

You should rather use a custom JSON converter to convert between the string values and the boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

As Martin Ullrich already suggested you should consider using a dedicated JSON converter.

I left null value handling for you.

```cs
public class OnOffStringToBoolConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private readonly Type _sourceType = typeof(string);
    private readonly Type _targetType = typeof(bool);

    public OnOffStringToBoolConverter()
    {

    }

    public override bool CanRead => true;

    public override bool CanWrite => true;

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        if (objectType == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(objectType));
        }

        return objectType == _sourceType;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(reader));
        }

        if (objectType == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(objectType));
        }

        if (serializer == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serializer));
        }

        if (reader.Value == null)
        {
            // Add some null handling logic here if needed.
            throw new JsonSerializationException(
                $"Unable to deserialize null value to {_targetType.Name}.");
        }

        if (string.Compare(reader.Value.ToString(), "On", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (string.Compare(reader.Value.ToString(), "Off", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        throw new JsonSerializationException(
            $"Unable to deserialize '{reader.Value}' to {_targetType.FullName}. " +
            $"This converter supports only \"On\", \"Off\" values.");

    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (writer == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(writer));
        }

        if (serializer == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serializer));
        }

        if (value == null)
        {
            // Add some null handling logic here if needed.
            throw new JsonSerializationException("Unable to serialize null value.");
        }

        // Write value only if it is boolean type.
        if (value is bool boolValue)
        {
            writer.WriteValue(boolValue ? "On" : "Off");
        }
        else
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationException(
                $"Unable to serialize '{value}' of type {value.GetType().FullName}. " +
                $"This converter supports deserialization of values " +
                $"of {_targetType.FullName} type only.");
        }
    }
}
```